# Allow OAuth2 Authentication into Existing AWS Amplify React Application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, oauth, oauth-2.0, aws-amplify

I have an existing React application that is using AWS Amplify for backend resources, namely Cognito for authentication. Users authenticate through Cognito to access application resources. I have a new use case where the application will be put into an iframe in another application and I need to accept OAuth2 authentication into my application along with the existing authentication. I have been reading up on OAuth2 and the documentation for Amplify Auth using OAuth2 and I'm a bit confused on how to go about doing this. I'm hoping somebody knows of better documentation or information that can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @Chris, were you able to figure this out?  I want to do something similar.  Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get this working. In fact, we have decided to move from Cognito to a third-party provider because Cognito is such a mess. The blocker for this is that Cognito will always force you to the sign-in page through an iframe when using OAuth. You can get around this by pushing the page into a popup from the iframe but it kind of defeats the purpose. I have another usecase where I iframed an application into Salesforce and with some tweaks it worked fine.